# Integration Test Asserting Each Element In A Collection

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, integration-testing, junit4

Considering an IT with Spring-Boot and JUnit that would test whether a collection returned from database contains all needed elements. What would be the best way to do that?

To illustrate, consider a JPA class/entity such as the following:

```
class Person {

    Integer id;
    String name;
    String lastName;
    Address address;
    Account account;

}
```

Consider that ids of `Person`, `Address` and `Account` would be auto-generated, so I can't infer them.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean to ask how you create 2 or more `Person` instances (will all required fields) - then use JPA to store them into the DB followed by a JPA call to fetch the list of `Person`s and verify all the fields (which you set when creating the instance) contain the same values as those obtained from the DB?

Comment: Yes... so so... Lets suppose I have an import script that inserts those objects in the database and then I also have a service which brings that information from many other services and putting them together into Person objects. What I need precisely is asserting that those returned objects are the ones I need.

Answer (score 1):

I identity 3 points :

1) **Invoke the method under test** that is save and flush the entity instance with the JpaRepository dedicated to your entity

2) **Make sure that your integration test is reliable/valuable**.
Here it matters to clear the first level cache of JPA (`EntityManager.clear()`) to test the actual retrieval from the database.  The cache may hide some issue in your mapping that will be seen only as the object is actually found from the database.

3) **Assert the expected behavior**  that is retrieve the saved entity from the DB and assert its state according to your expected.

For asserting fields of a object AssertJ could interest you.
It doesn't force you to override `equals()/hashCode()` and it is very simple and meaningful.
As you want to assert nested objects I advise to use a distinct `assertThat()` by object.
 For example :

```
Person person = new Person()...;
// action
personRepository.saveAndFlush(person);

// clear the first level cache
em.clear();

// assertions
Optional<Person> optPerson = personRepository.findById(person.getId());

// JUnit
Assert.assertTrue(optPerson.isPresent()); 
// AssertJ
person = optPerson.get();
Assertions.assertThat(person)
          .extracting(Person::getName, Person::getLastName)                     
          .containsExactly("expected name", "expected last name");

Assertions.assertThat(person.getAccount())
          .extracting(Account::getFoo, Account::getBar)                     
          .containsExactly("expected foo", "expected bar");

Assertions.assertThat(person.getAddress())
          .extracting(Address::getStreet, Address::getZip)                     
          .containsExactly("expected street", "expected zip");
```

Comment: At first, thank you for the answer. But in that case you are asserting only one object. I was wondering about asserting something like dozens of objects, considering filtering and sorting.

Comment: Asserting multiple objects is not really more complicated; But what do you mean by filtering and sorting ? You want to assert an actual list generally.